# Solving this 5x5 left triangular matrix for its constants, given the conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a matrix,

$\bar{L} = \begin{bmatrix} 
a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
b & c & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
d & e & f & 0 & 0 \\
g & h & i & j & 0 \\
k & l & m & n & o
\end{bmatrix}$

where: $(a + b + d + g + k) = (c + e + h + l) = (f + i + m) = (j + n) = o$ and $a, b, c, ..., o \in \mathbb{R}$

and we want to solve $a$ through $o$ on the conditions that all are greater than zero and the sums of each column are equal.

Assuming $\bar{L} \bar{x} = \bar{c}$,

where $\bar{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ w \\ v
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\bar{c} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \\ \delta \\ \theta
\end{bmatrix}$,

$x < y < z < w <v$,

$\alpha < \beta < \gamma < \delta < \theta$

How can this be solved if all elements of $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{c}$ are known and greater than zero?

Comment: what have you done?

Comment: @Shogun what do you mean? If you mean how have I attempted it; I tried putting it in to solvers on symbolab and wolframalpha, with no success. So, i tried to reduce the matrix to get the diagonal but Ii couldn't - but i also don't see how it would help given the conditions. Now i'm asking people who are smarter than me. This isn't an assignment or anything,  more of an 'applying maths to a real-life situation' thing for me, it isn't necessary but would make it easier.

Comment: I mean that if $\bar{x} , \bar{c}$ are given then did you multiply out $\bar{L}\bar{x}$.

Comment: yeah, thats how I formed the equation. I started with a concept then formed the matrix equation. But, with that, there are 15 unknowns ($a$ to $o$). So just multiplying out will not work since the constants aren't known.